# htaccess Rewrite Rules appending parameter?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Our original urls began with a parameter and the following rewrite works to redirect them  (thanks to Jon Lin).

However, the original parameter is being appended to redirect, so that

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^old-page$
RewriteRule ^$ /newpage [R=301,L]
```

ends up going to `mydomain.com/newpage?old-page`

Any idea how to fix? thanks again, 
Geoff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have it like this to strip off existing query string:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^old-page$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /newpage? [R=301,L]
```

Take note of `?` at the end of target URI, that is used to strip-off existing query string.

Comment: Thanks!  Whats the [NC] for?

Comment: `NC - No Case (ignore case)`