# Appending parameter via .htaccess results in loop

Tags: .htaccess

I'd like to append '?OpenBox=1' to example.com/de/Kontakt, so in the end it should look like this:

example.com/de/Kontakt?OpenBox=1

I initially tried to do this using a permanent rewrite:

```
RedirectPermanent ^de/Kontakt https://www.example.com/de/Kontakt?OpenBox=1
```

But apparently this ends up in a loop.

I checked the solution from here [htaccess Rewrite Rules appending parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21882533/htaccess-rewrite-rules-appending-parameter)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/Kontakt$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /?OpenBox=1 [R=301,L]
```

But this doesnt seem to do anything.

What am I missing? Thanks, Nouny

Comment: You are trying to check if the _query string_ portion of your URL is `/Kontakt`, which of course it isn’t. Your query string is `OpenBox=1`

Comment: And your RewriteRule tries to match a _completely empty_ path segment in the URL. The path in your URL is not empty, it is `de/Kontakt`

Comment: Thanks for your help CBroe.

Second try:
`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^de/Kontakt ?OpenBox=1 [R=301,L]`

That doesn't seem to work either. I wrote the condition to prevent a loop. Then, if de URL de/Kontakt is called, it should append the query string `?OpenBox=1`

Any tips?

Comment: _“That doesn't seem to work either.”_ - meaning what, exactly? No redirect at all, errors, …? (What exactly is the point of this here to begin with? If you _always_ want to set that parameter - then why is it required in the first place, why does the script behind this not do what it does based on this parameter being set, in any case then?)

Comment: My bad. Nothing happens, no redirect, no error. The parameter opens a box with contact details, which can be manually closed (popup-box).